# Prove that $f^{-1}$ exists and is differentiable on $(0, ∞)$ for $f(x) = x^2e^{x^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse

Let $f(x) = x^2e^{x^2}$, and assume that $(e^x)' = e^x$ for all $x$ in $R$.

a) Prove that $f^{-1}$ exists and is differentiable on $(0, ∞)$.

Proof: Suppose that $f(x) = x^2e^{x^2}$, then finding the derivative $f'(x) = 2xe^{x^2}(x^2 + 1)$. Then $f'(x) > 0$ when $x>0$ so f is strictly increasing by the Inverse Function Theorem, hence 1-1 on the $(0, ∞)$ for all $x$ in $(0, ∞)$. By the inverse Function Theorem, if $f'(a)$ exists and is nonzero, then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable. Then we conclude $f^{-1}$ is differentiable on $(0, ∞)$.

Can someone please verify this is enough for this proof. If not, can someone please give me feedback. Thanks.

Comment: You are right insofar as the reasoning goes, but you could be more detailed. $f'(x) > 0$ does not imply that it is monotone increasing, so maybe you want to elaborate on that. You also stated the Inverse Function Theorem correctly, so maybe you should show the details of how the assumptions of the Theorem are fulfilled before making the conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that if $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ and $f'$ is continuous implies that $f$ is injective (1-1) on $(0,\infty)$, but for $f^{-1}$ to exist $f$ needs to be also surjective (consider for example $x\mapsto (1-e^{-x})$). Since $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$, and $f(0)=0$, $f$ is surjective.

Otherwise your proof is OK.

Just remember that the inverse function theorem guarantees only a local inverse function, not global. In this case we can show that a global inverse exists and then use the inverse function theorem to prove that this inverse is differentiable.

Comment: Yes you are right, I should mention that f has an inverse if and only if it's both injective and surjective. By the global inverse, would $(f^{-1})'(b)$ = $1/f'(a)$ work?

Comment: The global inverse is of course also local, and satisfies $(f^{-1})'(b)=1/f'(a)$, where $b=f(a)$.